# Parsing a nested dictionary and finding highest value in Python

Tags: json, python-3.x, dictionary

I am running a script which returns the below json:

```
{
  "languages": [
    {
      "language": "so",
      "confidence": 0.003093857448475861
    },
    {
      "language": "mt",
      "confidence": 0.0028422382337627895
    },
    {
      "language": "sv",
      "confidence": 0.002833646520611977
    },
    {
      "language": "fi",
      "confidence": 0.0006320737767975471
    },
    {
      "language": "nn",
      "confidence": 0.00046142993421229
    },
    {
      "language": "eo",
      "confidence": 0.0004201385148033488
    },
    {
      "language": "nl",
      "confidence": 0.9421574512
    }
  ]
}
```

What I want to do is print the key for the 'confidence' that is closest to '1' so in this example, I want to return 'nl'. My variable for this dictionary is 'language'.

I tried the below but it didn't work given the dictionary is nested but my plan was to then add the keys and values to dictionary list and then identify the value nearest 1

```
for (k, v) in language.items():
    print('Key: ' + k)
    print('Value: ' + str(v) + "\n")
```

Any suggestions how I can identify the value that is closest to the value of 1 in my returned data?

Thanks

Comment: you first say closest to 0 then later you say nearest 1. Which one is it?

Comment: Is this is a typo? Did you mean close to 1?

Comment: Sorry closest to 1 - my apologies. Edited

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over the languages dicts. set the first lang as your closest match. then iterate over the remaining languages and compare the confidence with the current best confidence match. In this case I am saying closest to 0 I.E the smallest confidence but you can change this to highest by changing  < to >

```py
data_dict = {
  "languages": [
    {
      "language": "so",
      "confidence": 0.003093857448475861
    },
    {
      "language": "mt",
      "confidence": 0.0028422382337627895
    },
    {
      "language": "sv",
      "confidence": 0.002833646520611977
    },
    {
      "language": "fi",
      "confidence": 0.0006320737767975471
    },
    {
      "language": "nn",
      "confidence": 0.00046142993421229
    },
    {
      "language": "eo",
      "confidence": 0.0004201385148033488
    },
    {
      "language": "nl",
      "confidence": 0.9421574512
    }
  ]
}

my_conf_lang = data_dict['languages'][0]
for lang_dict in data_dict['languages'][1:]:
    if lang_dict['confidence'] < my_conf_lang['confidence']:
        my_conf_lang = lang_dict

print(my_conf_lang)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
{'language': 'eo', 'confidence': 0.0004201385148033488}
```

Comment: Why so hard? Why is not just `sorted(languages, key=lambda obj: obj['confidence'])[0]`?

Comment: nice @funnydman very succient. sometimes when I see code in the OP question it leads me on a path without looking for any other solutions.